# Proper way to add a service?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-15

I've just installed and config'ed noip on my server, but I'm unsure on how to make it *always* run.

I'm guessing:

```
chkconfig --levels 235 noip on
/etc/init.d/noip start
```

I've checked `/etc/init.d/` and there is a `noip` file there... Sorry for a newb question, but I don't want to mess up my configuration. :-)

Also, could anyone explain the `--levels 235` argument? I'm really fresh, but I understand there are certain runlevels?

Comment: You're on the right track. A simple Web search turns up what you are after: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel  *man chkconfig* will also help

Comment: when i do chkconfig --levels 235 noip on it will start that service every time i enter the runlevelse 2, 3, 5? and /etc/init.d/noip start will start it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install noip through yum? The yum RPM package should install the noip service script in /etc/init.d/ for you. Run the following commands as root to install and setup noip through yum.

```
yum install noip

noip2 -C

service noip start
```

To configure the noip service to automatically run at startup, run the following command as root.

```
ntsysv
```

If you really want to know the nitty gritty details of adding a service, here's a good tutorial on manually adding a service.

http://www.thelinuxblog.com/adding-a-service-on-fedora/

To answer your second question, the **--levels** parameter tells which run levels a an operation should run in. Linux has seven run levels by default. Each run level can start different set of services. For example, Runlevel 1 will put the system into **Single User Mode**, which only starts most basic services and puts you into a root shell. Runlevel 3 is multi-user mode with no GUI. Runlevel 5 is similar to Runlevel 3 except it also includes the (GUI). Runlevel 6 is another special mode that will reboot the system.
More detail about run levels can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_level)

Comment: Note, I'm using fedora17, and the ntsysv is no longer supported.
Instead I used `systemctl enable noip.service`. I had no idea `yum` would be so useful.

That aside, I just spent hours fiddling, installing, uninstalling, and rebooting trying to do what you so simply outlined in this answer. Thank you.